# Demando pri "lasi" kun "I-verbo"

Tags: meaning-in-context

En esperanta [blogero](http://lingvatereno.blogspot.com.es/2015/05/kial-zamenhof-ne-povis-antauvidi-la_1.html) el la blogo de Jouko Lindstedt, mi trovis la jenan frazon (ĝuste en la fino de tiu blogero):

> Esperanto estas maniero lasi la realon surprizi.

La signifo ŝajnas klara: *Esperanto lasas, ke la realo surprizu iun aŭ ion* (nin, la mondon, ktp.). Tamen, ĉar surprizi estas objekta verbo (transitiva), eblas ankaŭ alia interpreto: *Esperanto lasas, ke io aŭ iu surprizu la realon*.

Mi jam legis la klarigon pri *[lasi kun I-verbo](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/gravaj_verboj/lasi.html#i-rgo)* en PMEG:

> Se la I-verbo mem estas objekta verbo, ofte nur la kunteksto povas
>   montri, ĉu la objekto apartenas al lasi aŭ al la I-verbo: [...]
>
> *Mi **lasis min** moki. = Mi lasis, ke mi moku iun*. Aŭ: *Mi lasis, ke oni moku min*. Ambaŭ signifoj eblas. La kunteksto montras, ke la dua
>   signifo estas ĝusta.

Bedaŭrinde mi ne kapablas distingi la ĝustan interpreton, eĉ legante la kuntekston, kiun mi montras jene:

> Esperanto jam fariĝis io alia ol Zamenhof kaj la unuaj esperantistoj
>   planis kaj antaŭvidis. Ĝi ne plu estas projekto, kiu atendas la
>   aprobon de interregna kongreso. Ĝi havas kulturon, kies unuavica celo
>   ne estas akceptigi la lingvon ĉe UN aŭ la Eŭropa Parlamento. En
>   *Infana raso* aŭ *Poemo de Utnoa* abundas signifoj, kiujn nur ni, parolantoj de Esperanto, povas plene kompreni kaj aprezi. Esperanto
>   estas la lingvo inter mi kaj mia filino, kiu ĝuste nun laboras ĉe la
>   apuda komputilo. La tutmonda angla estas evidenta realaĵo; Esperanto
>   estas maniero lasi la realon surprizi.

Mia demando estas jene: ĉu la ĉi-supra lasta frazo celas al tio, ke Esperanto surprizas la realon, aŭ al tio, ke per Esperanto la realo surprizas (nin, la mondon)?

Comment: Mi timas, ke la ununura, kiu povas doni al vi certan respondon, estas Lindstedt mem...

Comment: Lindstedt estas lerta esperantisto, kio pensigas min, ke eble ĉi-kaze li ludas per ambigueco, tiel ke la leganto decidas la ĝustan interpreton. Ĉiuokaze, la fina mesaĝo ŝajnas klara, ke Esperanto surprizas la realon aŭ nin mem (aŭ ambaŭ).
Ĉar Lindstedt estas via kolego ĉe la Akademio de Esperanto, estus interese scii lian respondon se vi iam havos la okazon demandi. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Oni ne povas surprizi la realon, ĉar la realo ne posedas personajn atributojn.  Pro tio, ŝajnas klare (almenaŭ miaopinie) ke li penas diri, ke li konsideras ke Esperanto estas maniero lasi ke la realo surprizu (al la gehomoj, kiuj pensas ke estas evidente ke la angla estas tutmonda). Alivorte, ĉiuj pensas ke la angla estas tutmonda lingvo, kaj Esperanto estos surpriza realo por ili.

Comment: Eble oni vere ne povas surprizi la realon, sed certe oni uzas tiajn frazojn eĉ en la angla (almenaŭ laŭ Google): _now I know that a work of art must be able to surprise reality; the aim of Spriggs’ approach is to surprise reality; he wanted to surprise reality in its lair_. La interpreto de la ĉi-koncerna frazo ŝajnas klara sed ne estas tutcerta, laŭ mia opinio.